# using GCC -D option

Tags: c, gcc

I did a minimal c file (main.c)

```
#if !defined(MBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE)
    #error "not defined"
#else
    #include MBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE
#endif

int main(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

now calling `arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c` gives `error: #error "no defined"` and this is OK.

But calling `arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE="test.h"` gives `error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>` so it is defined but not to the value I expect.

What is the correct syntax ? (context: this is working from the IDE but I want to move to cmake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *shell* that removes the quotes from the string you pass. You need to escape the quotes to keep them in the macro:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"test.h\"
```

Comment: working. And for cmake I needed to escape the escape char and the double quote. Thanks

Comment: Also try `-DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE='"test.h"'` which may be more palatable to cmake.